# How to animate multiple children while scrolling using 'flutter_animate' package

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to animate many widgets such as `Text()`, `Image.asset()` and other stuff when they are visible. I tried multiple libraries for checking visibilty of Widgets inside a `SingleChildScrollView()` but all solutions were either very complicated or it takes a lot of coding to achieve it for multiple widgets. The question that is most similar to mine is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000039/how-to-animate-a-widget-when-it-becomes-visible-in-flutter), but it is simple for one or two widgets, but it will be messy for many Widgets. Can someone help me in achieving this requirement?

Edit:

I found that 'flutter_animate' depends on controllers, such as ScrollController, but no documentation about it was mentioned.
[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate#adapters-and-controllers)

Comment: what animations do you mean? those that depends on current scrollcontroller scroll offset?

Comment: yes I need a scollcontroller that initiate the animation for each widget that is begining to be visible while scrolling @pskink

Comment: this might help https://gist.github.com/pskink/d9775e4dc8bbc5586070229760106031

Comment: could you explain your code? @pskink